# SQL - How to make first column the headings of a result set?

Tags: sql, pivot

So I have this table to show stock levels so:

```
select * 
  from Stock
```

Would give:

```
Branch     Product    ActualStock   OrderedStock
------------------------------------------------
London     Product1       3              2
Paris      Product1       9              4
Rome       Product1       6              3
London     Product2       3              2 
Paris      Product2       9              4
Rome       Product2       6              3
```

I want to be able to write a query to view the `ActualStock` at each branch in this format:

```
Product      London    Paris    Rome
-------------------------------------
Product1        3        9        6
```

How can I do this?  Any ideas?

Comment: Search for `pivot` and the database you are using. If you add a tag for the actual database you're using then we can direct you to the appropriate answer (this is a common question and has been answered many times before).

Comment: Google your database name followed by "pivot", if you know all the branches you want in the headers.  If the branches are determined only by the data, they use "dynamic pivot" instead.

Comment: Also, note that this type of dynamic pivotting is generally a SQL-Code-Smell.  It indicates that you're restructuring your data for presentation to a user rather than for data processing.  This coupling of presentation to SQL is considered bad practice as it leads to maintenance problems, complex code, silent failures and other issues.  In the vast majority of cases this should be done out-side of SQL, in the presentation layer of your application.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

This will work.

Use group by product then calculate sum of ActualStock for each branch in a group.

```
SELECT 
     [Product]= Product,
     [London] =SUM( CASE WHEN Branch ='London' THEN ActualStock ELSE 0 END ),
     [Paris] = SUM( CASE WHEN Branch ='Paris' THEN ActualStock ELSE 0 END ),
     [Rome] =SUM( CASE WHEN Branch ='Rome' THEN ActualStock ELSE 0 END )
FROM Stock
GROUP BY Product
```

Try this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28fcd/1)

Comment: Its MS SQL 2008 i'm using. Apologies for asking an already answered question.. I did try and find it.. just failed. haha.}

Also...  obviously the table I really have contains thousands of rows. So the answer would need to apply to my actual table. Seems I need to look into Dynamic Pivots...